# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Not Being Recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm writing this node.js app and I've got a weird situation:

This snippet of Angularjs...

```
// delete hosts
$scope.delete = function(row) {
    var rowData = {
        hostname: row.hostname,
        ipaddr: row.ipAddress,
        location: row.location,
        vp: row.vp,
        virthost: row.virtHost,
        services: row.services
    };

    var delurl = "http://10.2.201.6:666/deleteserver";
    var jdata = "mydata="+JSON.stringify(rowData);

    $http({
        method: method,
        url: delurl,
        data: jdata,
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        cache: $templateCache
    }).
    success(function(response) {
        console.log("success");
        $scope.codeStatus = response.data;
        console.log($scope.codeStatus);
    }).
    error(function(response){
        console.log("error");
        $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed";
        console.log($scope.codeStatus);
    });
    $scope.list();
    return false;

};
```

is calling this node.js bit...

```
//// DELETE
app.delete('/deleteserver', function (req, res) {
    console.log("DELETE: ");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://10.2.201.6");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.mydata);
    var row = JSON.parse(req.body.mydata);

    db.servers.remove(row, function(err, result) {
        if(err) { throw err; }
        res.end(console.log("Record deleted"));
    });


});
```

But for some reason I'm getting the following errors in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.2.201.6:666/deleteserver. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.2.201.6' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've banged my head against a wall, a desk, and a window trying to figure out why the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is being ignored. Yes, the listen on port 666 is normal. In fact, my GET and POST methods have the same *res.header(...)* code and they work brilliantly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you use `DELETE` method, then browser first send `OPTIONS` request and your application have to response to this request with right headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need to add DELETE to res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

Also, don't you want res.send not res.end?